# fetching data from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with following format:

```
prod_code   prod_pos      prod_nm     prod_price

1           1             product1     100

1           2             product2     200

1           3             product3     400

1           4             product4     500
```

Now I need to fetch the record in following manner

product code, product_nm and productprice where prod_pos='1' and product_pos and prod_prod_price where prod_nm='product4'

Its bit complicated may be confusing too but please help me with this guys.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might also want to post something to Sql fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) to help people try out potential answers.

Comment: And do you want to fetch 1 table or 2 table?

Comment: @jonny I have fetched the first part i.e. SELECT DISTINCT prod_code, prod_nm, prod_price where prod_pos = '1' but the 2nd part i.e. where prod_nm='product4' is not done..

Comment: I want to fetch it in a single table

Comment: So you want to dynamically choose which columns to `SELECT` based on some criteria?

Comment: You may wish to provide a desired result set in your question.. the description is mega confusing.

Comment: do u want row 1 and row 4 in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild stab in the dark:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE prod_pos = 1
    OR prod_nm = 'product4';
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
select prod_code
       , Prod_NM
       , Prod_Price 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE 
Prod_Pos = 1 
 AND 
   Prod_NM = 'Product4';
```

Comment: its giving me blank row

Comment: It will do. Nothing equates to having Prod_Pos = 1 and Prod_NM = 'Product4'

I would also advise re-wording your question, if this isn't what you need then it is extremely confusing what you are actually asking for.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT A.PRODUCT_CODE FIELD1, A.PRODUCT_NM FIELD2, A.prod_price FIELD3,
B.prod_pos FIELD4, B.prod_price FIELD5
FROM product_table A, product_table B
WHERE  A.prod_pos = 1 AND B.prod_nm = 'product4'
```

---

**EDIT AGAIN**:

```
with product_table as
(
select 1  prod_code,         1    prod_pos,         'product1'  prod_nm,   100 prod_price from dual
union
select 1  prod_code,         2    prod_pos,         'product2'  prod_nm,   200 prod_price from dual
union
select 1  prod_code,         3    prod_pos,         'product3'  prod_nm,   300 prod_price from dual
union
select 1  prod_code,         4    prod_pos,         'product4'  prod_nm,   500 prod_price from dual

)
SELECT A.prod_code FIELD1, A.prod_nm FIELD2, A.prod_price FIELD3,
B.prod_pos FIELD4, B.prod_price FIELD5
FROM product_table A, product_table B
WHERE  A.prod_pos = 1 AND B.prod_nm = 'product4'
```

Gives following output for the input given in question:

```
FIELD1                 FIELD2   FIELD3                 FIELD4                 FIELD5                 
---------------------- -------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -------------
1                      product1 100                    4                      500
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Check if you need something like this:

```
SELECT 'TYPE1' TYPE, product_code FIELD_1 , product_nm FIELD_2
WHERE prod_pos = 1

UNION 
SELECT 'TYPE2' TYPE, prod_pos FIELD_1 , prod_price FIELD_2
WHERE prod_nm = 'product4';
```

This will return an output like

```
TYPE   |  FIELD_1   | FIELD_2
TYPE1  |  1         | product1
TYPE2  |  4         | 500
```

You can access in the same resultset with FIELD_1 and FIELD_2 differentiated by type

Comment: is there any way to display this 2 row in a single row

Comment: @user3305327: Check my edit. I hope it is close to what you need.

Comment: yes its very close but when am using DISTINCT in this query the result is still showing duplicate values...how to display oly DISTINCT resultsets?

Comment: It is coming in a single row only. Please check my edit again with CTE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_table
WHERE 
   prod_pos = 1 
AND 
   prod_NM = 'Product4';
```

or if u want this 1 column less:

```
SELECT 
  prod_code as p_code_or_p_pos
  , prod_price
  , prod_nm
FROM product_table
WHERE 
   Prod_Pos = 1 
union ALL
SELECT 
  product_pos as p_code_or_p_pos
  , prod_price
  , ''
FROM product_table
WHERE 
   Prod_Pos = 1
```